# What type of analysis to choose for this data?

Tags: r, time-series, clustering, cross-correlation

I am trying to create a model of refrigeration having the energy consumption and the temperature over time. So far, I've tried regression but fitting this data into linear model seems impossible. Another thing that I've tried is cross correlation but it's insignificant (around 0.11 at lag 0). I also clustered the data and for another fridge I was able to state that if the fridge is in 'idle mode' (e.g. not consuming electricity) the temperature goes above certain value. However, for this fridge, this doesn't work as the data seems pretty random. Here is a scatter plot of the data, the bigger the circle, the higher the frequency.
[image]

Any ideas what type of analysis can I use to derive insights from this? I would like to know if there is any correlation between the kW data and the temperature data. A new plot for the full duration that I have:

[image]

Comment: Can you please explain, what do you mean by "frequency" here?

Comment: Do you have the full time series?

Comment: Ah, sorry, I didn't realize that it's unclear. I mean how often those values appear in the data set. So the small dots are values which appeared only once while the big ones are values which appeared multiple times.
I have time series for 6 months, collected every 15 minutes so it's 4 measurements per hour. There are some missing values so I divided the data into chunks because of this.

Comment: What is the goal of the analysis? Which questions do you want to ask the data?

Comment: If there is any correlation between the kW data and the temperature data.

Comment: This seems to need a proper time-series analysis, which can be a bit more involved than standard linear regression.

Comment: "If there is any correlation between the kW data and the temperature data." Please add this to the question.

Comment: What is "temperature data" here?

Comment: The y axis represents the temperature of a product in Celsius. It's a sensor inside the fridge which simulates a product (glycerin bottle) as the air temperature changes faster and product temperature is more stable and interesting. I also have the air temperature but it is basically the same 4 clusters with a slight shift of the degrees.

Comment: Well, do look at *duration* as suggested below. You want to look at **Watt times duration** (i.e. you want to measure **kWh** not kW - or **Joule**). Clearly a fridge that uses 0.6 kW, but only for 1 millisecond did not really "cool" anything. Joule is the appropriate unit for measuring "effort".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You clearly have a bimodal (multimodal for the second) distribution:

- standby (on the left)
- cooling (on the right)

It does not seem that the temperature settings affects the power intake.

Most likely, the fridge operates "binary", i.e. if the temperature is too high it starts cooling, and when it is cool enough it stops cooling again. Typical operation, because it's better to operate the cooling engine at a well-defined power intake and speed; and use duration to control.

Look for a correlation between **cooling *duration*** and temperature setting instead. The unit you want to observe is **Joules, not kW** (note that Joules relate to kWh!). I'd expect a correlation with Joules (= effort), not with power. Consider the power consumption of an appliance to be a sequence of constanta (off/on, or off/low/high); and expect them to use the *time* to steer the total effort.

Consider your stove. It probably has 4-6 different power settings only. In order to boil water (or anything), you would turn it on (probably to the highest setting; limited by e.g. safety considerations) and then *wait* for the water to boil. If you want to measure how much energy your stove used, you need to use "watt * time" (yielding kWh or Joules), one value is useless without the other.

Comment: +1 The idea of looking at duration is insightful and appealing.

Comment: Thank you. That seems as a very good suggestion for a start. However, if I expand the data into bigger period, I have this: http://rpubs.com/canar40/102389 which means 4 types of operation. I'm sorry, I should have uploaded this graph instead. I will try to look for patterns for 4 of them now.

Comment: Still, clearly *no correlation* with the temperature setting in that plot either.

Comment: Thank you for that! From my column with kWh gathered every 15 minutes, I took the difference (as it is simply metering data which adds up in time) and now I have proper consumption. However, I still can't find any correlation, even with the difference of my temperature data, ccf is 0.09 at lag 1. I am trying to exclude the defrost cycles now to see if something will change as the fridge does not use energy during that time but the temperature raises. I will be glad if you have any other suggestions!

Comment: If you look at a fixed time (e.g. 15 minutes) then you are again not taking duration into account. You need to aggregate *durations*, not split them into 15 minute chunks.

Comment: I am not sure I am able to aggregate duration as I have the temperature available each 15 minutes as well. That is actually why I took the temperature difference. In this case, I have the difference between time(i-1) and time(i), let's say 2 degrees and that the fridge consumed 0.03 kWh to decrease the temperature to this level. Am I missing something? By aggregate duration you mean on a longer basis, e.g. hourly, daily?

Comment: Aggregate *multiples* of 15 minutes, depending on how long it has been cooling. Assuming that cooling cycles can take longer than 15 minutes. But it may well be that this data is too coarse, and should have been measured differently the first place.

Comment: I guess you are right. Measuring this data on 15 minutes intervals is not enough. Here is a graph of my data http://rpubs.com/canar40/fridge (the red line is the kWh and the black is diff(air). It's clear that I observe the Cut In/Out process (https://www.refrigerationbasics.com/RBIII/controls1.htm) each 15 minutes.